# How do I access the return value in "Evaluate expression"?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I have this code:

```
return changeState(...lots of parameters...)
```

and I want to use the result of `changeState()` in an expression in the debugger. It's not allowed to call this method a second time.

I know that I could assign the result to a local variable and return that.

Is there a way to access the return value in an expression in the debugger without changing the code?

Comment: You can add a method to the [watchers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/examining-suspended-program.html#watches) list to track its return value or enable `Show Method Return Values` the in the debugger tool window settings. If you need something more advanced feel free to create a new issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA